# Can't create new Facebook App

Tags: facebook

Whenever I try to do something with Facebook developers page, most of the times it doesn't work the way it is supposed to. Today I tried creating a simple app on their developers page and after the CAPTCHA I got this message -

> "Something went wrong. We're working on getting it fixed as soon as we
>   can."

I verified this with a friend, and his worked without any concern. Any help/pointers would really be appreciated.

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. We cannot help with errors or issues with Facebook itself. Contact Facebook directly for issues related to problems with accessing Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

(this is supposed to be a comment but, sadly, I do not have enough reputation.)

I would usualy think this has something to do with the internet connection or the browser you are using. Maby (unlikely but worth a try) you have javascript or cookies disabled? It could also be to do with a faulty ad blocker or something (maby). Hard to say to be honest.

If you tried fixing the above and nothing worked you should probably ask on facebook or report it as a bug ([developers.facebook.com/bugs](http://%20developers.facebook.com/bugs) as said by WizKid)